# Running Camel-K with Shared Object dependency

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I have a JAR file that I need to use with my class. I deployed the JAR into a hosted maven repository. The issue I have is that the JAR file needs to reference a .so library file (someLibrary.so). This file is 6.5MB in size, so I cannot include it as a resource file. I am not sure how I can get this into the Camel-K pod when I run.

The error shown from the JAR is:

```
SEVERE: Failed to load native library 'SomeLibrary' (with java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib):
[1] no SomeLibrary in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
[1] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SomeLibrary in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
```

My script (run.sh) that I use to run this is:

```
kamel run --dev \
--name some-test \
-d mvn:org.apache.camel:camel-spring:3.6.0 \
-d mvn:org.apache.camel:camel-core:3.6.0 \
-d mvn:org.apache.camel:camel-core-engine:3.6.0 \
-d mvn:org.apache.camel:camel-kafka:3.6.0 \
-d mvn:org.apache.camel:camel-api:3.6.0 \
-d mvn:org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 \
-d mvn:org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.30 \
-d mvn:com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 \
-d mvn:com.some:someLibrary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT \
Tester.java \
--property-file application.properties \
--resource dataset.json
```

I appreciate any help with getting me to use the .so file. Thank you!

Comment: wonder if the so can be included in the application jar or some other dependency jar

Comment: Hi Ascalonian, have you solved the issue? I encountered the same problem and dont know what to do?